# Error using the module discord.py on fedora

Tags: python, discord.py

hello i have this error when i use discord.py with python version 3.11:

```
  discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/Documents/programe/import discord.py", line 20, in <module>
    client.run('6KhBCVw8fSwljDww6aoo_hgFKl6Ij4Rl')
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 805, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

the English language is not my native language I apologize for the language errors. Thank you in advance for your response.

I already tested the pip install -U yarl command and nothing works after

Comment: The error is `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`, which means the token you've put in is not your token. Where did you get your token from?

Comment: it's mine I took it on the discord site

Comment: @Amato21 Make sure the token you are passing is the exact same as the one in discord's developer portal.

Comment: @Filip it's the same one I copied from the SECRET CLIENT section

Comment: @Amato21 Client secret is not token of the bot. You can look at this [example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html#discord-intro) on how to get the token.

Comment: @Catgal thank you it works I was wrong